# Protractor - see text on page

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm trying to write a test in Protractor, without highly coupling my test to specific markup of the page.

For example, given a typical log in page I'd want to test that if incorrect credentials are provided, an error message appears.

The way that my markup would display that error is:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        <li>Invalid username or password.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This unordered list may contain other errors, too - so I don't want to make an assertion on the list element itself. In any case, I may decide to move away from displaying the error as a list, and may want to show it in some other way.

All I want is to be able to assert that the *page* contains: **Invalid username or password.**

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
expect(page.getContents()).to.contain('Invalid username or password.');
```

But of course this doesn't work.

Are there any methods available in Protractor that can allow me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use element.getText().

https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText :

> Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, **including sub-elements**, without any leading or trailing whitespace.

To get all the text from your list. And then `expect(text).toContain("Invalid username or password")`

example using angularjs.org:

```
 browser.driver.get('https://angularjs.org/')
    el = element(by.css('.first'))
    el.getText().then(function(text){expect(text).toContain("AngularJS is a toolset for")});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xPath to select the DOM element that contains the text you are looking for and, then, check if this element exists.

I'm using this code and

```
var myText = "Invalid username or password.";
var selectedElement = element(by.xpath("//*[. = '" + myText + "']"));

expect(selectedElement.isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true, "This text is not present in page.").and.notify(callback);
```

I've tested the snippet on your example and works. Note, I'm using chai-as-promised, so, if you don't recognize the sintax don't worry. The important thing is that the second part: `expect(selectedElem)...` is used to check if the element is present in page.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('*', 'Invalid username or password.')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```